# Break from jquery for loop when doing an ajax call return error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a look at the code below. The question is simple , how do I break from this for loop if the method  findUserInfo ajax code returns an error. In short how can I break from this for loop whenever I wish to ? Is is because ajax call is asynchronous ?

```
 jQuery.each(d, function() {
    findUserInfo(this);
 });

function findUserInfo(userID){


var req = $.ajax({
url: "http://twitter.com/users/show.json?suppress_response_codes&id=xx!5@x!!x",
dataType : "jsonp"

});

req.success(function(msg) {
    console.log('Yes! Success!');

});

req.error(function(msg) {
    console.log('Error');
});


}
```

Comment: breaking the loop won't help for the same reason you mentioned (async call)

Comment: You can't.  AJAX calls are asynchronous, meaning they run in the background, and the loop continues on.  There's no way to return from the AJAX call to the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, jQuery.ajax is asynchronous, so you need to use something like:

```
function findUserInfos(datas){
  var userID=datas.shift(); //remove and return the first element

  var req = $.ajax({
    url: "http://twitter.com/users/show.json?suppress_response_codes&id=xx!5@x!!x",
    dataType : "jsonp"
  });

  req.success(function(msg) {
    console.log('Yes! Success!');
    findUserInfos(datas)
  });

  req.error(function(msg) {
    console.log('Error');
  });
}   

findUserInfos(d);
```

It will broke, as soon as there is an error, since we continue only in the success.

Answer (score 1):

Setting async:false is a terrible idea. It causes the browser to hang while the ajax call is made.  [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) was designed to solve problems like this:

```
jQuery.each(d, function() {
    findUserInfo(this);
});

Frame.useTimeout = false; // turn off Frame's error recovery

function findUserInfo(userID){

    Frame(function(next){

        var req = $.ajax({
        url: "http://twitter.com/users/show.json?suppress_response_codes&id=xx!5@x!!x",
        dataType : "jsonp"

        });

        req.success(function(msg) {
            console.log('Yes! Success!');
            next();
        });

        req.error(function(msg) {
            console.log('Error');
            // don't call next and Frame will stop
        });

    });

}  
Frame.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

To break from the loop, return false

If you throw an error inside your error handler:

```
throw 'Error: ' + userID;
```

You can then write

```
jQuery.each(d, function() {
    try {
        findUserInfo(this);
    } catch(err) {
      return false;
    }
 });
```

Edit: As commented by others, It would be better to return true from your success handler and false from your error one, and then calling return findUserInfo(this); inside the loop.
Of course, if you make your ajax calls synchronously you risk freezing the browser.

Comment: try catch produces a new execution context. the performance it consumes depends on the inner executions... doing it for a loop break like seems pretty hacky to me as well...

Comment: Note that @Tronix117 is right about doing this the way you're trying.

Comment: true for the return false to break an each, but here it can't really work, since the ajax request is asynchronous. It means, we can't know the result of the ajax request outside the success or the error, findUserInfos will not return anything, and the loop will continue.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing all the IDs as an array, transporting them to the server and then checking a given result!? That saves a lot of requests. You could collect the IDs as an array and transport them via POST `["id1","id2",...].join(",")`

Or you fetch everything in advance and start your loop after fetching...

breaking out the loop is not possible due to the asynchronous nature as you already stated... async: false; could help as well, but it prevents the UI from updating (which will keep the browser busy due to many requests)

Comment: Dont want to load my server with twitter api calls.

Comment: sorry I don't know about the twitter API but just at the moment you are doing at least one call for the first userID... if you could send ALL ids at once and get the results you could iterate and still only have one request... if that is possible via twitter API > no idea

Answer (score -1):

you can make the ajax call synchronous one by setting async: false for the ajax call. You are already having the error function to catch all exceptions. So I believe that should do

```
           $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/abc/GetNodesById",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "nodeId": '' },
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
              //Do Work
            }
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                // Handle Error
                // Return False 
            }
      });
```

Comment: made as async as false , but how do I break from the for loop

Comment: Not the better solution, because async:false, can freeze the browser.